# How can I explicitly assign a receiving variable to be an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, methods

ok, so, I was doing this before and its working:

```
let array = [];
if (blablabla) array = ["foo","bar"];
else array = ["this", "that"];
FunctionImUsing(array)
```

And then the method will receive the array correctly and no problem.

```
this.FunctionImUsing = function (array) {
//works with the array inside the function. No problem
}
```

However, I wanted to do this:

```
if (blablabla) FunctionImUsing(["foo","bar"]);
else FunctionImUsing(["this","that"]);
```

But it doesnt work. the method receives only the first element and not the full array. How can I force the receiving variable to be an array?

I tried this

this.FunctionImUsing = function (**array[]**) {

but Javascript wont let me do that (Unexpected Token). I wanted to force the receiving variable of a function to be an array.

Comment: The first `FunctionImUsing` should be working as you're expecting. Which means you're either leaving out critical information or misinterpreting the results.

Comment: I want to use the second

Comment: "the method receives only the first element and not the full array" This is not correct. Both call formats work the same way. Again, this means you're either leaving out critical information or misinterpreting the results.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, it was missing a [ one of the statesments. Lol